# Laravel 4.2 package development on top of Authorize.net SKD - where to put Constant Variables?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing my first Laravel package in workbench to solve a business need which is to integrate the Authorize.net SDK for our systems billing transactions.

I've got most of my code now working and I can call the SDK functions via my custom facade like so AuthorizeMe::authorizeAndCapture();  My issue is the Authroize.net SDK requires use of defined variables.  Their example usage is as follows:

```
define("AUTHORIZENET_API_LOGIN_ID", "YOURLOGIN");
define("AUTHORIZENET_TRANSACTION_KEY", "YOURKEY");
define("AUTHORIZENET_SANDBOX", true);
$sale           = new AuthorizeNetAIM;
$sale->amount   = "5.99";
$sale->card_num = '6011000000000012';
$sale->exp_date = '04/15';
$response = $sale->authorizeAndCapture();
if ($response->approved) {
    $transaction_id = $response->transaction_id;
}
```

I would like to 1) store the defined variables in the packages config.php file, 2) I would like to make it so if I do publish the package other users can simply publish the config file to their app/config/packages folder so they can simply put in their unique api info.

I have tried to store the API variables in the config.php array as follows:

```
return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Define credentials
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Your credentials for both live environment and sandbox
    |
    */

    // Live environment
    'LIVE_LOGIN_ID' => 'YOUR ID',
    'LIVE_TRANSACTION_KEY' => 'YOUR KEY',

    // Sandbox evnironment
    'SANDBOX_LOGIN_ID' => 'YOUR SANDBOX ID',
    'SANDBOX_TRANSACTION_KEY' => 'YOUR SANDBOX KEY',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Define environment
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Dictates if we're in sandbox mode or live mode
    |
    */

    'SANDBOX' => true,
);
```

I don't believe defined variables can be set from within a class so I'm not sure how to use the config file to accomplish my needs.

For example, something like this doesn't seem to work:

```
class MyClass {
     public function __construct($app=null)
     {
       $this->app = $app ?: app();
     }

     public function billClient()
     {
       define("LIVE_LOGIN_ID", $this->app['config']->get('LIVE_LOGIN_ID'));
     }    
}
```

Lastly, I don't want to re-write the vendors package to simply work with my implementation as I feel it's important to make sure my package wrapper just sits on top so that it can pull in any future updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your static data that can change depending on what server your software is running on inside of the [environment root-level configuration file](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#protecting-sensitive-configuration).  I would suggest doing this also to avoid the possibility of your API keys getting committed into source control (which could potentially be damaging).  You can also leverage this to have different configuration values in different environments.  Quoting from that linked to manual entry:

> For "real" applications, it is advisable to keep all of your sensitive configuration out of your configuration files. Things such as database passwords, Stripe API keys, and encryption keys should be kept out of your configuration files whenever possible

The general practice is to keep these defined in a config file named `.env.{environment name}.php` which *does not* get checked in to source control.  You can also specify them inside of the virtual host for the site if that works better for you, with e.g. `SetEnv` directives for Apache.

Comment: thanks for the info. you're correct - the example should have used define instead of defined, I've updated my post.

Comment: I took a quick glance through the classes and it looks like everywhere where they are trying to grab those constants, they are also passing those values in via the constructor or the method.  I believe you can get away without defining anything in your app and having your wrapper take care of all that through the environment variables.

Comment: This has been very helpful, your advice has me almost there - the biggest issue I have now is I would like to be able define the api values somewhere once so I don't have to define then in each method like billClient, then again in refundClient, etc. any advice?

Comment: And instead of using the $this->app['config'] I took your earlier advice and defined a .env.local.php file with the values and used the $_ENV['VARIABLE'] in the define function with success.  Thank you.

Comment: I've also update the example above to reflect where the $this->app... is coming from